# Deallocating Template Objects on the Stack

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class that looks like the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "entry.hpp"
#include "hashes.hpp"
using namespace std;

const double MAX_LOAD = 0.5;

template <typename K, typename V, typename H = GenericHash<K> >
class HashMap
{
    public:
        HashMap(size_t init_capacity){
            entries = new Entry<K, V> *[init_capacity];

            for(int i = 0; i < init_capacity; i++){
                entries[i] = NULL;
            }

            num_entries = 0;
            capacity = init_capacity;
        }
        ~HashMap(){
            for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
                if(entries[i] == NULL){
                    continue;
                }
                delete entries[i];
            }
            delete entries;
        }
```

In a file called main.cpp, I allocate a Hashmap like the following:

```
HashMap<int, int, IntHash<int> > hmap(MEDIUM_SIZE);
```

This doesn't use dynamic memory allocation, but the actual code for HashMap does. When the function finishes, will the destructor for `hmap` be called? Or do I have to do something else in order to free the memory allocated by `hmap`?

Comment: This is why you should prefer the term "Automatic Storage" to "stack". Automatic tells you that what is going to happen is automatic. Stack doesn't tell you jack.

Comment: You should make sure to follow the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). Right now, your compiler is silently generating a copy constructor for your class which almost certainly won't do what you expect.

Comment: btw there are no "template objects". `HashMap` is the template, `HashMap<int, int, IntHash<int> >` is a type and `hmap` is an object of that type no different than objects of other types

Comment: There's nothing about this question for which the fact that `hmap` is an instance of a class that is itself an instantiation of a template is relevant, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does  `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::array` or `std::pair` count as templated objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  For objects with automatic storage duration (e.g. local variables in functions), the destructor is always called as soon as that object goes out of scope.

This is one fundamental piece of ["RAII"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).  This pattern is frequently used to create objects that "clean up after themselves."  For example:

```
struct Resource {
    File file;
    Resource(std::string filename) : { file = open(filename); }
    ~Resource() { close(file); }
};

void foo() {
    // some code

    { // start a new scope
        Resource r{"path/to/file"};
        // some code using r
    } // r.file is automatically closed here because r has gone out of scope

    // some more code
}
```